# Make Samba files accessable

Tags: samba

I download sometimes files with a download manager called JDownloader on my Debian NAS. This download manager runs the user/group: jdownloader:jdownloader!
But when I try to access these files from Windows Samba I have no permissions to use. How to make these files accessable for my windows user? Do I have to edit the samba.conf and allow my Windows user or what I have to do?! I don't want to set chmod 777 to this directory.